# Firebase HTTP cloud function .send() what does it return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, https, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying get a value from a firebase cloud function with my Android App.

The cloud function is the following:

```
 exports.checkIfNumberExists = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("numbers");
    var query = ref.orderByKey();
    var exists = "false";
    query.once("value" ,function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                if(childSnapshot.key === request.query.number){
                    exists = "true";
                }
            });
            response.send(exists);
        });
 });
```

I don't understand what type of data does that `.send()` function return,
I asume it is plain text, but yesterday firefox got it as json when the `exist` value was boolean and not string.

Opening the url with firefox returns `true` or `false`, but when I try to make an http get request from Android or Javascript it denies access to it.

What is the return type of `.send()` function?

Comment: What does that mean: "when I try to make an http get request from Android or Javascript it denies access to it"?  What access is denied?

Comment: When I try to create a HTTP GET request from firebug using javascript I get an error that sais the following (Translated into english): `request from other source blocked:  the politics of the source deny reading the remote resource in https://theurloftheservice.net (reason: CORS header missing)`

Comment: I don't know the configuration of the thing you're trying to build, but you might want to read up on CORS to figure out if there's something you need to implement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing  If you do need CORS, there are official samples for that: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll read it and try to figure it out.